# Why Does vbScript "And" Operator cause an Overflow Error?

Tags: vbscript

Why does this cause an overflow in vbScript during a bitwise AND comparison?

```
response.Write cDbl(2147483648) And cDbl(1)
```

Comment: The funny thing is that if I do an `On Error Resume Next` the operations work correctly. 

Darn, OK, That is what I feared. I will have to come up with some alternate solution on this one. Basically, I have an enum of bit values ranging from 2^0 to 2^31, which I need to test for in the codebase. Not sure how I am going to accomplish this.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/12/03/integer-arithmetic-in-vbscript-part-two.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. Can you help me understand how I can use that information to do what I am trying to do in the above example?  I don't quite understand what is being said in the article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a work-around solution to this problem using server side javascript wrapped around a vbscript function. It seemed much simpler than what was proposed in the Eric Lippert article.

Solution is as follows:

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server">
    //bitand function for JS
    //vbscript cant handle bitwise operations cleanly on values above 2^30
    function bitandJS(a, b) { return a & b }
</script>
```

Then I wrapped it in a vbscript function for consistency in my application:

```
Function bitand(byVal a, byVal b)
    bitand = bitandJS(a, b)  'done via server side JS
End Function
```

Though its not as clean as I would like e.g. having to mix languages, it works flawlessly for my purpose.